# scala: regular expression to replace words ending in dot

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying the following:

```
scala> " in gral.  case".replaceAll("""(?imx) \bgral\.\b """, "(*)")
res14: java.lang.String = " in gral.  case"
```

The problem seems to be the second \b, because if I try with

```
scala> " in gral.  case".replaceAll("""(?imx) \bgral\. """, "(*)")
res16: java.lang.String = " in (*)  case"
```

it works

I think the problem is that "." is itself a word separator, so how can I indicate a word separator that is NOT the dot??

--edit

what I'm trying to accomplish is to remove several abbreviations that may or may not be sufixed with a dot, like this (they are street names)

```
"xxx av av. avenue" -> xxx
"yyy dr dr. doctor zzz" -> yyy zzz
```

so I was trying with something like

```
"xxx".replaceAll("""(?imx) \b(?:av\.|av|avenue|dr\.|dr|doctor)\b""", "")
```

but I get the following

```
scala> "xxx av av. avenue".replaceAll("""(?imx) \b(?:av\.|av|avenue|dr\.|dr|doctor)\b""", "")
res30: java.lang.String = "xxx  . "

scala> "yyy dr dr. doctor zzz".replaceAll("""(?imx) \b(?:av\.|av|avenue|dr\.|dr|doctor)\b""", "")
res31: java.lang.String = yyy  .  zzz
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what you want to accomplish. The reason, why it doesn't work is that `\b` matches between `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but the position you are trying to match is between two characters of the latter group. Could you provide a few examples that should match and a few that should fail?

Answer (score 1):

This one should work for you:

```
replaceAll("""(?im)(^\s*)?\b(?:av\.?|avenue|dr\.?|doctor)(?!\w)\s*""", "")
```

(see [this demo](http://ideone.com/4PHGd8))

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it

The problem is that in fact I want to recognize a separate word (wihtout consuming the separator) containing a character which itself is a word separator, like m.buettner correctly commented

If I just use \W (not a word char) as separator, consuming it, I would loose two adjacent words I'm trying to match, like this

```
scala> "dr. de. xxx av av. avenue av.".replaceAll("""(?imx) \W(?:av\.|av|avenue|dr\.|dr|doctor)\W""", "")
res3: java.lang.String = dr. de. xxxav.av.
```

In this case I match the first " av " (yes, with the space too) and the first " avenue ", and I can't match the fist "av." nor the last one.

So I need to match the separator, without consuming them.

For that, I used look ahead and lookbehinds, like this:

```
scala> "xxx av av. avenue".replaceAll("""(?imx) (?<=\W)(?:av\.|av|avenue|dr\.|dr|doctor)(?=\W)""", "")
res4: java.lang.String = xxx   avenue

scala> "yyy dr dr. doctor zzz".replaceAll("""(?imx) (?<=\W|^)(?:av\.|av|avenue|dr\.|dr|doctor)(?=\W|$)""", "")
res5: java.lang.String = yyy    zzz
```

and a more tricky example (that explains why I must match \W but also ^ and $)

```
scala> "dr. de. xxx av av. avenue av.".replaceAll("""(?imx) (?<=\W|^)(?:av\.|av|avenue|dr\.|dr|doctor)(?=\W|$)""", "")
res6: java.lang.String = " de. xxx    "
```

I'm no regular expression guru, so if anybody can think of a better way please let me know...